# Is any way to add translations for Braintree Gateway dropin interface?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

The correct way to add translation to an instance of braintree.dropin is to add options.translations array when calling the braintree.dropin.create method, for example:

```
if ($dropinUi.data('locale') == 'el') {
          options.translations = {
            payingWith: "Πληρωμή με {{paymentSource}}",
.... and then ....
braintree.dropin.create(options, function(err, dropinInstance) {
....
```

work fine, but I can do it only directly in **DropnUi.js** file from /vendor/_path_to_braintree-gateway and this is wrong way.

What is right way to extend gateway and add translation fields? Via custom module with event or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Though I haven't found an answer, here are some potentially helpful links:
- [Craft Braintree plugin docs](https://github.com/KuriousAgency/commerce-braintree) - [Braintree JS docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/javascript/v3) - [Braintree translations (js)](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/tree/master/src/translations) - The [craft plugin page](https://plugins.craftcms.com/commerce-braintree) doesn't mention language switching as a feature, so it's not guaranteed to be easily possible... I hope you can find a workaround or someone answers!